# How to send request to third party api?

Tags: c#, api

I have a third party api they have given xsd document.

What I have done is that I have created class with the given xsd document and serialized and passed that as data.

But I am not getting the result,Is this the right way

**My code to serialize **

```
              stream = new MemoryStream(); // read xml in memory  
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
            // get serialise object
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, emp); // read object
            int count = (int)stream.Length; // saves object in memory stream
            byte[] arr = new byte[count];
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            // copy stream contents in byte array
            stream.Read(arr, 0, count);
            UnicodeEncoding utf = new UnicodeEncoding(); // convert byte array to string


            return utf.GetString(arr).Trim();
```

Comment: A little more information would be nice. Post your whole code: what is `Test` or `emp`? What is your actual problem?

Comment: Test is the class which was created with the xsd provided by third party and emp is obj of test class

Comment: public partial class Test {
        
        private string dataField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string Data {
            get {
                return this.dataField;
            }
            set {
                this.dataField = value;
            }
        }
    }